# Were the Deathly Hallows invented for book 7?

Tags: harry-potter

When I read "Deathly Hallows", the whole idea seemed to be less organic to me. Unlike Horcruxes that were foreshadowed ever since "Chamber of Secrets" and subsequent books, the idea of Hallows seemed to be something JKR just stuck into the seventh book as a "last moment" idea.

Did Rowling address this somehow in terms of when she started planning for the idea of Hallows?

Comment: While I think they were planned, I agree with you that they seemed a bit like something she didn't think of until writing book 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did Rowling invent the Deathly Hallows, or borrow them from existing legends/stories?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53625/did-rowling-invent-the-deathly-hallows-or-borrow-them-from-existing-legends-sto)

Comment: I disagree about possible duplicate. I don't think the user is asking about them being "invented" for the book, but if they were planned in advance (as opposed to some last-minute idea).

Comment: Related, but not dupes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ring with the resurrection stone curses Dumbledore's hand between books 5 and 6, and Harry's invisibility cloak exhibits special properties (though we don't realize it) since book 1.  I'm unaware of any references to the elder wand, though.  So, no, this clearly couldn't have been a last-minute addition solely for book 7.

Comment: Good catch! +1. Elder Wand was not mentioned, but the idea that Voldemort would need some other wand than his was foreshadowed by ending of Goblet of Fire

Comment: `though we don't realize it` - Eh, sort of.  There was a mention at some point (possibly by Ron?  Or in _Fantastic Beasts_ under one of the creatures used to make cloaks?) about how invisibility cloaks normally fade over time, although it wasn't specified how long that is.  (I kinda remember it being Ron, with the point made that Harry's cloak still looked new, but I'm pretty sure I was corrected on this before)

Comment: There are hints at the Elder Wand in pre-DH interviews: JKR says that she can’t say what Dumbledore’s wand is made of, because it’s going to turn out to be significant later.

Comment: All of this sounds decidedly like retcon territory, picking a bunch of random magical artifacts from early books and imbuing them with special properties.

Answer (score 11):

> JKR: Yeah, I sent them a list of plausible titles, including the real one. **Hallows of Hogwarts for years was going to be the title of the seventh**
>   (JKR [discussing fake book titles](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306023723/http://harryahistory.com/2009/01/vault-8-seabottom-and-the-hall.html) from Seabottom company).

So, she planned to have Hallows - and even named them as such - a long time ago.

Obviously, she introduced the Hallows as items in earlier books as well - Invisibility Cloak was given to Harry back in Year One; whereas Dumbledore tried to put on a cursed Resurrection Stone (cum Horcrux) before Year 6, which led to him dying (and we know that without the Hallows legend, there was no point in him putting the ring on).